# Unable to open any apps installed inside the WindowsApps folder

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-store-app, microsoft-store

From one day to the next all of a sudden all the applications installed via the Microsoft store that live in the WindowsApps folder will not open. When I try opening an app from a shortcut created when installed I get the following error: [Specified path does not exist error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsVOW.png)

I should add that the Microsoft store itself works fine, and I can install/uninstall apps, I just can't run them once installed.

I can go inside the WindowsApps folder and find the exe's I need, but trying to run them gives mixed problems. For example, the Windows Terminal app will just give an application was unable to start correctly error when I try to open. YourPhone.exe and Microsoft.Photos.exe fails because it cannot find various dll's.

When I try to run the ubuntu distribution for wsl installed from the Microsoft store (ubuntu2004.exe), the terminal actually opens but gives an "Access is Denied" and exits right away.

When I first got all these errors, it seemed like a permissions issue, so I ran icacls on the WindowsApps folder to try and reset the permissions to what they should be but it didn't solve the problem. I also ran all updates, ran all the applicable troubleshooters that come with Win10, and tried using the repair and reset options available in the settings for a windows app.

Currently, the Owner of the WindowsApps folder is Users (MyDesktop\Users). This is what the permissions look like: [WindowsApps Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cjfn.png).

My chkdsk scans come up clean. I'd like to refrain from a reset to my OS since it would be very painful to set back up my development environments, so I'm here since I don't know what else to try.

Thank you in advance for help

Comment: When you install an APP like Windows Terminal (installed here) then it runs from the main Start Menu. Other apps, the same thing. Did you try that?

Comment: I'm note sure if I understand your suggestion, but when I try running WindowsApps from the start menu I get errors that I mentioned above. Again this is only for apps installed through the Microsoft Store. 3rd party programs that install inside the program files folder don't have this issue.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood your use of the word "Shortcut"  Try running DISM and SFC:   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Thanks, I ran the commands you mentioned, the DISM commands ran successfully and SFC found no integrity violations, then after a reboot the problem I'm having has still persisted unfortunately

Comment: The next step is a Windows 10 Repair Install. Use the Media Creation Link. Use the second choice and then run in place. Use the option to Keep Everything.